# What is causing this unexpected behavior in my Chrome cookies?

Tags: php, google-chrome, cookies, logout

I am using a cookie named "token" to hold a base64-encoded string.  I would log out by deleting that cookie.  My logout stopped working in Chrome, and my deleted cookie would show up again when I refreshed the page.

I created a minimal HTML page to better understand the problem... and became more confused.  I need some help with this.  My expectation was that the simple PHP line would create a "token" cookie, overwriting the previous one if it existed.  What I see instead, is two cookies, both named "token"; one leftover from logging into the original page, one created by this page.  The javascript to delete the "token" cookie deletes the new one, but leaves the original intact, even when "Logout" is clicked multiple times.

```
    <?php
    setcookie("token", "MakeMeDisappear", time()+3600);
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Logout</title>
    <script>
    function showCookie() {
        document.getElementById("problem").innerHTML=document.cookie;
    }
    function logout() {
        document.cookie = 'token=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
        showCookie();
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Logout Test</h1>
    <p><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="logout()">Logout</a></p>
    <pre id="problem"></pre>
    <script>
    showCookie();
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I initially see in the output:

`token=MakeMeDisappear; token=ftBIUXQJnezKeaTycgh_rEBK9PBq7IhT7t50v5CkaV2Ws9qp5H9Agx-P6sUPnc9Bq90PGm9S4P-6g5AQJNGO3vhO1EuBpdOnJHXnmkSijq79ISOKVkkhSHQAo_7XSFtT4gHTBHA4q1MMN1VwKOO3iF-pbsUbxnwjG2VtNlAdOnUu2AS6I163tx_CsoxJuQCaR4Dft3y-HLyYwfL1VkZoowU_JelzHLg_wGfLQf5bNskuxAn-3uaddsyCiDjXOqKsSIAy5lLWFYgQPnIHgggH0hjoeJjoLni3X1UShCalaD3IlEXjrul3aZydw3CCTLZKm8Gl-9wv4Rp1vBBZ2FOrFmmlIcZcbUB5xSfp9x_A1s_ftUmARKw_EAJo0Y_s8iAXpoYsXoo2ihqews4m9NUopdN4FjeEV4jB-vJFF4O3JGUHWPmWpy-98bHcHPstv3uKI05EvdtnPXeG4fN3OdMrpuj5WEltpCKbBaRCLI-kqPjyHrzHydJTJ7WW4vVjRSIO`

When I click on the `Logout` link, I then see:

`token=ftBIUXQJnezKeaTycgh_rEBK9PBq7IhT7t50v5CkaV2Ws9qp5H9Agx-P6sUPnc9Bq90PGm9S4P-6g5AQJNGO3vhO1EuBpdOnJHXnmkSijq79ISOKVkkhSHQAo_7XSFtT4gHTBHA4q1MMN1VwKOO3iF-pbsUbxnwjG2VtNlAdOnUu2AS6I163tx_CsoxJuQCaR4Dft3y-HLyYwfL1VkZoowU_JelzHLg_wGfLQf5bNskuxAn-3uaddsyCiDjXOqKsSIAy5lLWFYgQPnIHgggH0hjoeJjoLni3X1UShCalaD3IlEXjrul3aZydw3CCTLZKm8Gl-9wv4Rp1vBBZ2FOrFmmlIcZcbUB5xSfp9x_A1s_ftUmARKw_EAJo0Y_s8iAXpoYsXoo2ihqews4m9NUopdN4FjeEV4jB-vJFF4O3JGUHWPmWpy-98bHcHPstv3uKI05EvdtnPXeG4fN3OdMrpuj5WEltpCKbBaRCLI-kqPjyHrzHydJTJ7WW4vVjRSIO`

I can't seem to get that second "token" cookie to disappear in Chrome, and when I test in Edge, I see only one instance of "token".  I've tried deleting all cookies, but the problem comes back.  Am I doing something wrong or is something flaky happening in my browser?

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out.  I wasn't specifying the path in the cookie.  I had originally developed and tested my login in the root folder, and subsequently migrated the script into an "/account" subfolder.  Long story short, that cookie was defined with a default path of "/account" and was distinct from a cookie of the same name defined in the root folder.